# How do I get the full URL in Apache httpclient of a page I am redirected to after authentication?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am writing a program that needs to access the cPanel API (https://api.docs.cpanel.net). To use the API I need to be authenticated and have the cPanel session id so that I can build my URL. For example to add a new FTP user I would use the following URL - https://hostname.example.com:2083/cpsess##########/execute/Ftp/add_ftp?user=username

When authenticating in cPanel in a browser, the user is redirected to the cPanel home page and the cPanel session id is displayed in the URL.

I am using Apache HTTP client version 4.5.13. I have no problem authenticating using the following code:

```
        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(domain, 2083, "https");
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));

        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        authCache.put(targetHost, new BasicScheme());

        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
        context.setAuthCache(authCache);

        // disable the redirect
        //HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();

        // dont disable the redirect
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(
                new HttpGet(url), context);

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(statusCode);

        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();

        for (Header header : headers) {
            System.out.println(header.toString());
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            // return it as a String
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
```

However when I print out my headers I do not have a Location header so I can not get the URL that contains the session Id.

If I disable the redirect using the line that is commented out above:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
```

Then I do get a Location header. However it only provides me with the end of the URl like:

Location: /frontend/paper_lantern/index.html

I need the full URL like:

https://someURL.com:2083/cpsess3886765014/frontend/paper_lantern/index.html

So that I can get the cPanel session Id (cpsess3886765014) in the above URL.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured this out. I can use the following code:

```
List<URI> redirectLocations = context.getRedirectLocations();
        for (URI uri : redirectLocations){
            System.out.println(uri.toASCIIString());
 }
```

And I can get the redirects